# Gmail API search returning 404 error for some emails

Tags: javascript, api, synchronization, gmail, gmail-api

I am using the Gmail API to synchronize my emails, and I am encountering an issue where some of my emails are returning a 404 error when I try to search for them. This is happening for both scheduled emails and emails in my inbox.

I have reviewed my API request and verified my authorization, but I am still experiencing the same issue. I have also confirmed that the emails do exist by checking directly in my Gmail account.

Are there any other troubleshooting steps I can take to resolve this issue? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I want to solve the issue why I'm getting 404 status from Gmail to some emails. How can I solve this?

I'm getting `Response object is undefined.`

```
.then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                // Response is successful, continue processing
                return response.json();
            } else {
                // Log error message or throw an error
                console.error('Failed to fetch data. Status code:', response.status);
            }
            })

        .then((data) => {

            if (!data.ok) {
                console.error(`Failed to retrieve data. Status code: ${data.status}`);

                // Check if the response object is defined
                if (data.headers && typeof data.headers.get === 'function') {
                    // Check if the 'Content-Type' header is defined
                    if (data.headers.get('Content-Type') && data.headers.get('Content-Type').includes('application/json')) {
                        // If so, parse the response body as JSON and log it
                        data.json()
                            .then(parsedData => console.error('Response body:', parsedData))
                            .catch(error => console.error('Failed to parse response body as JSON:', error));
                    } else {
                        // If not, log the response body as text
                        data.text()
                            .then(textData => console.error('Response body:', textData))
                            .catch(error => console.error('Failed to retrieve response body:', error));
                    }
                } else {
                    // If the response object is not defined, log an error message
                    console.log(data);

                    console.error('Response object is undefined.');
                }
            }
```

Comment: Ensure that the API credentials you are using have the necessary permissions to access the email you are trying to retrieve. You may need to check and adjust the scopes of your authorization.

Comment: @Joker I think, I have necessary permission, the problem I face in few of email not all, like if 30 email will search then problem will be in 4 emails.

Comment: Verify that the emails causing the 404 error are still present in your Gmail account.

Comment: or Wait for a few minutes and try again. It's possible that the emails are still syncing with the API and are not yet fully available.

Comment: @Joker yes these are still present in my Gmail account.

Comment: Double-check your API request to ensure that it is correctly formatted and includes all required parameters.

Comment: If none of these steps work, you may want to consider reaching out to the Gmail API support team for further assistance.

Comment: @Joker I have update the question and few code add.